# How can I convert a DataTable to an XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, datatable

I want to convert a DataTable to an XML file in C#. How can I do this?

Comment: I posted an answer here that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868607/datatable-to-xdocument-custom  You can control exactly how the XML will be built (i.e. what to store as attributes, what to name elements, what to store as child-elements, etc...).  It uses `XDocument`, which you could easily code to save to a file using `XDocument.Save(FileName)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to get this done is by adding the data table to dataset and calling the `GetXml()` on the dataset.In addition to this dataset is equipped with the `WriteXml()` and `ReadXml()` for writing/reading the XML directly to/from a file path or stream.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt1); // Table 1
ds.Tables.Add(dt2); // Table 2...
...
string dsXml= ds.GetXml();
...
using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(xmlFile)) // XML File Path
{
      ds.WriteXml(fs);
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use **[DataTable.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx)** Method.

Here is an example;

**[How can i convert my datatable into XML using C# 2.0?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1441971.aspx/1?How+can+i+convert+my+datatable+into+XML+using+C+2+0+)**

```
string result;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
dataTable.WriteXml(sw);
result = sw.ToString();
}
```

If you don't actually need a string but read-only, processable XML, it's a better idea to use MemoryStream and XPathDocument:

```
XPathDocument result;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
dataTable.WriteXml(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
result = new XPathDocument(ms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first method encloses a row with TABLE tags. Is there any way I could replace it with custom tags, like ROW ? Of course, I could search the string itself and replace TABLE with ROW, but I want a different approach.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `writeXML` method to save it as XML ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx)).

You can also use serialization/desirialization as described in the fifth post of this [forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1441971.aspx/1?How+can+i+convert+my+datatable+into+XML+using+C+2+0+).