# DataTable to Xdocument Custom

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

i have a datatable that looks like the following

```
type                cname   ctable      text          allowgroupping
StringFilter         AAA     Table1      Good,Bad      Yes
StringFilter         BBB     Table2      Ugly          No
StringFilter         CCC     Table3      Lucky         Yes
```

and from that table i want to produce the following XML

```
<Filters Date ="25.07.2012 22:50">
<StringFilter cname="AAA" ctable="Table1" allowgroupping="Yes">Good,Bad</StringFilter>
<StringFilter cname="BBB" ctable="Table2" allowgroupping="No">Ugly</StringFilter >
<StringFilter cname="CCC" ctable="Table3" allowgroupping="Yes">Lucky</StringFilter >
</Filters>
```

- the type column represents the tag
- the cname and ctable and allowgroupping are attributes
- column text represents the inner text

can you please help me achive this using linq and xDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;

var XDocument doc = new XDocument();
var root =  new XElement("Filters");

var items = dt.Rows.AsIEnumberable().Select(row=> new XElement("StringFilter",             new XAttribute("cname",(string) row["cname"]),
    /*additional attributes here*/
     (string) row["text"]  ));

root.Add(items);
doc.Add(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

@CamBruce has the correct answer.
The `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` is unnecessary
   if you use `AsEnumerable` instead of `AsIEnumberable`.
Below is a working example with Child-Elements:

```
//Build DataTable for the purposes of this Example:
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//Add Columns:
dt.Columns.Add("WidgetType");//The default Type is "string".
dt.Columns.Add("WidgetID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("WidgetName");
dt.Columns.Add("WidgetPrice", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("SubWidget");
//Add Rows:
dt.Rows.Add("Watch",  1, "Dial",     .50, "Gear");
dt.Rows.Add("Tablet", 2, "Screen", 14.99, null);
dt.Rows.Add("Watch",  3, "Strap",   1,    "Buckle");

//Prep XML Objects:
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
//xDoc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null);//Optional: SQL-Server already stores XML using UTF-16.  The default for XDocument is also UTF-16 when the Declaration is null. - 07/26/2018 - MCR.
XElement xRoot = new XElement("Root");
xRoot.SetAttributeValue("Date", string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}", DateTime.Now));//Optional: Add Attribute to Root.

//Populate XML from DataTable:
xRoot.Add(dt.AsEnumerable()
            //.Where(r => r.Field<string>("WidgetType") == "Watch")//Optional: Add Filter.  This works.
            .Select(r => new XElement(r.Field<string>("WidgetType"),//Add Row Element
                                      //r.Field<decimal>("WidgetPrice"),//Optional: Populate Element Value.
                                      new XAttribute("WidgetID",   r.Field<int>("WidgetID")),//Optional: Add Attribute.
                                      new XAttribute("WidgetName", r.Field<string>("WidgetName")),//Optional: Add Attribute.
                                      new XElement("SubWidget", r.Field<string>("SubWidget"))//Optional: Add Child-Element.
                                     )
                   )
         );

//Finish assembling the XML:
xDoc.Add(xRoot);

//View the XML Data:
string sDoc = xDoc.ToString();//View Indented-XML as a string.

//View the XML as it would appear in a Standalone File:
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
xDoc.Save(sw);
string sWrite = sw.ToString();//This adds the XML Declaration to the string output.
```

sDoc String:

```
<Root Date="07/26/2018 04:07 AM">
  <Watch WidgetID="1" WidgetName="Dial">
    <SubWidget>Gear</SubWidget>
  </Watch>
  <Tablet WidgetID="2" WidgetName="Screen">
    <SubWidget />
  </Tablet>
  <Watch WidgetID="3" WidgetName="Strap">
    <SubWidget>Buckle</SubWidget>
  </Watch>
</Root>
```

sWrite String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root Date="07/26/2018 04:07 AM">
  <Watch WidgetID="1" WidgetName="Dial">
    <SubWidget>Gear</SubWidget>
  </Watch>
  <Tablet WidgetID="2" WidgetName="Screen">
    <SubWidget />
  </Tablet>
  <Watch WidgetID="3" WidgetName="Strap">
    <SubWidget>Buckle</SubWidget>
  </Watch>
</Root>
```

Use this to pass `XDocument` as an `Xml` Parameter Value to a SQL Server Sproc:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@WidgetXml", SqlDbType.Xml).Value
 = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml(xDoc.CreateReader());
```

If writing to a File, I'd use `xDoc.Save(FileName)`.
If you want to preview exactly the how the XML will appear in a File, then use `StringWriter`.
If you want a basic/simple view of your data elements while debugging  / troubleshooting,
   then you could use `xDoc.ToString()` when stepping through your code, but note that it may be missing a few things like the Declaration.

I'm no XML expert, but I think `StringWriter` and `xDoc.Save(FileName)` should add the additional/necessary information to your XML Output (even beyond the XML Declaration - depending on which Properties you set in your XML Variables).
Maybe someone could weigh in on their past experience in the comments.