# Writing a DataTable from a query to xml

Tags: c#

Currently, we generate a shipping manifest file using VBA. I was able to take care of the grunt work of harmonizing, and getting the dataset I need, converted to C#, my last step is to generate the XML file in C# is as well.

The way it works currently, VBA opens a `recordset` called `tblXMLcodes` which has 4 fields, `Tag`, `Carrier`, `Section`, and `orderct`.. `Tag` has each tag I need, `carrier` is always the same, section is either **Item**, or **Package** as I have two data sets *(a package query and an item query)* Then the orderct field is just numbered 1-16 for each section.

Then another `record` set is opened from the item query AND the package query and it gets looped through appending to a .txt file..

How can I easily take my two datasets (both queries) and loop through them to generate an XML file..

Are there any NuGet packages?

Any help is appreciated.. Currently my code works so I wont post it, but if someone wants to see the current I will gladly share. It is VERY slow....

Comment: I you have already a C# DataSet instance created (System.Data.DataSet) and populated with your data you can use a StreamWriter and write an XML using the data set WriteXml function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259759/how-can-i-convert-a-datatable-to-an-xml-file-in-c

Comment: I need to be able to control exactly what tag says what, should I use xDocument instead?

Comment: Did you try using XmlDocument?

Answer (score 0):

follow this code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt1); // Table 1
ds.Tables.Add(dt2); // Table 2...
...
string dsXml= ds.GetXml();
...
using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(xmlFile)) // XML File Path
{
      ds.WriteXml(fs);
}
```

Comment: that's the code from the URL i shared. I think it's not the solution based on Tyler's comment.