# Convert datatable to xml with 15k records in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 15k records in datatable and I am unable to convert datatable to xml, getting outofmemory exception in asp.net c#.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream)) {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, dt);

        if (memoryStream.Position > 0) {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
        }

        xmlDoc.Load(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample code of your issue.

Comment: XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream)) {
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, dt);
                    if (memoryStream.Position > 0) {
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    }
                    xmlDoc.Load(memoryStream);
                }
            }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a DataTable to an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259759/how-can-i-convert-a-datatable-to-an-xml-file-in-c)

Comment: What i am missing the code, it is throwing exception at xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, dt); line.

Comment: How many records are being serialized? Looks like you're trying to serialize a huge amount of data into a MemoryStream, and as a result, running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use this  method DataTable.WriteXml if your version .net is permit this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable customerTable = GetCustomers();
DataTable orderTable = GetOrders();

ds.Tables.Add(customerTable);
ds.Tables.Add(orderTable);
ds.Relations.Add("CustomerOrder",
    new DataColumn[] { customerTable.Columns[0] },
    new DataColumn[] { orderTable.Columns[1] }, true);

System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
customerTable.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, false);
```

Comment: How to load writer into xml document. Could pls give sample on that